# Gnome session has missing letters, transparency issues, blue screen

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I've install the GNOME desktop with `sudo apt-get install gnome`, [as instructed here](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-install-the-gnome-desktop). It is not working properly, as shown below.

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/iyqe9]

Comment: Do you use a proprietary driver (System Settings -> Additional Drivers) for your graphics card?

Answer (score 3):

First try to restart your **GNOME SHELL** as follows-

Press <kbd>ALT+F2</kbd>

in the run command option enter the letter **"r"** and hit enter.Your shell will restart.

If this doesn't work,You maight have to reinstall **GNOME SHELL**.

To remove **GNOME SHELL** open the *terminal* and enter the following command-

> `sudo apt-get purge gnome`

and then to re-install **GNOME SHELL** enter the command-

> `sudo apt-get install -y gnome`

*You may also remove and add the **GNMOE SHELL/GNOME DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT** from the **Software Center** but the termial use would be better.*

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/y928td06f/                             even my terminal is not visible,in gnome shell.. see the image

Comment: did you try restarting the gnome shell by the `Alt+f2`method?

Comment: If you have and that did not work,

log-out,and before logging in select the session to UBUNTU(unity)[I suppose you know to do it] and log in in unity and then remove GNOME.you should rather actually that itself.You should not log in in GNOME session and remove Gnome.IT will caude problem.So log in in unity and then remove GNOME

Comment: i restarted it also using alt+f2
i did ol the above commands.. also for uninstalling and reinstalling.. but aint working even.. it just removed 52 kb space and after installing back.. filled up 52 kb again.. but when i installed it earlier it used around 500 mb space

Comment: i uninstalled it using gnome classic session...............

Comment: okay then try the software center method.But remember to remove not only **GNOME DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT** but also **GNOME SHELL** you will mostly have to remove both seperately from software center

Comment: NO...dont log in into any gnome session.Log in in UNITY

Comment: how to do that.. pls tell me using gnome terminal.. its quite easy for me

Comment: okayz.. i will now.. use ubuntu 2d session

Comment: yeah use that and then at first try the terminal method..If using `sudo apt-get purge gnome` removes only 50kb,try `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell`

Comment: okay.. what i did now was.. started ubuntu 2d session..
opened terminal.. used sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell command.. it removed around 1064 kb space.. and then in the same terminal installed it back using sudo apt-get install -y gnome-shell .. it installed around 900 kb space.. but the problem remain the same for gnome session.. same image as the above one..

Comment: Go the Software Center way...There is nothing Difficult in it...I'll post another answer with screenshots for your ease...

Comment: okay.. give me some screen shots....

Comment: okay i found it.. software center has.. **gnome shell** and **gnome shell extension prefrences**  shall i remove both..

Comment: i have given you the tutorial above as a new answer.My suggestion would be to *NOT* remove **gnome shell extension prefrences**

Comment: problem unchanged.. did every thing u told in 2nd answer

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the GUI way to remove **GNOME DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT** and **GNOME SHELL**

Let me bring to your notice that the 500Mb you had installed when you installed **GNOME** was because it included the *DEFAULT GNOME APPLICATIONS,ETC*

The problem you are facing is actually with **GNOME SHELL**-The actual component responsible for the **GNOME GUI ENVIRONMENT**

So you maight not free as much space as you installed.Because you are not Deleting the APPLICATIONS.

Now the procedure-

1. Start the Software Center from the launcher.
2. In the search bar, enter *GNOME* as shown below-

[image: gnome s]

3 .After the search returns the results,you will see the 1st result as ***GNOME DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT***

Click on the <kbd>*REMOVE*</kbd> Button against it as shown below-

[image: gnome s2]

4.After Removeing the *ENVIRONMENT* add to the search bar **SHELL** as shown-

[image: shell s]

5.After the search results are dispalyed,you will get the 1st result as ***GNOME SHELL*** as shown-

[image: shell 2]

Click on the <kbd>*REMOVE*</kbd> Button against it.

After this is done,Restart Your computer.

When the log in screen appears,Click on the sessions menu and you will find that all options of the **GNOME ENVIRONMENT** are absent.

Log in into the available UNITY environment and INSTALL gnome the same way from the **SOFTWARE CENTER** as you removed it..In place of the <kbd>*REMOVE*</kbd> Button yu will see the <kbd>*INSTALL*</kbd> Button...

Comment: I uninstalled it.. and then reinstalled it.. still the problem is unchanged :(

Comment: Well i tried searching the internet too but i cant find any info.You may consider reinstalling UBUNTU itself..running the update 1st after the reinstall and installing gnome b4 installing anything else.Thats the order i had followed when i reinstalled 12.04.idk if this is has anything to do with it running correctly but it worked perfectly for me in this way atleast. Sorry i couldnt help :(

Comment: okay.. stay with me.. i am new to linux.. i want to use ubuntu.. all its features.. its exciting.. 
so tell me step wise step what shall i do.. like command by command.. lets start with first uninstalling ubuntu.. i instslled ubuntu using [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)[link] this..

Comment: Okay..Dont worry..The community is certainly here to help you.M glad you like LINUX..Now,you have installed UBUNTU thru WUBI thei windows installer.Unfortunately i do not have an experience in using WUBI.Just search as a new question how to uninstall UBUNTU WHICH HAS BEEN INSTALLED THROUGH WUBI.after you  succeed in doing it,i would recomend you to DUAL BOOT your system and not INSTALL THROUGH WUBI.It is always better.SO you first learn that and then i can guide you through HOW TO INSTALL UBUNTU ALONGSIDE WINDOWS(aka HOW TO DUAL BOOT YOUR PC WITH WINDOWS).

Comment: hmm.. okay nirmik.. thankx for ol.. i will first serch how to unistall..

Comment: yeah sure.. NO problem :)